# Solve $z^3-3z^2+3z+7=0$ and sketch solution set

Tags: complex-numbers

> Solve the equation $$z^3-3z^2+3z+7=0$$ and sketch solution set.

---

My work:

Since $z=-1$ is a root of the equation then we proceed by doing Ruffini's Rule we observe that $$z^3-3z^2+3z+7=(z+1)(z^2-4z+7)=(z+1)(z-(2+\sqrt{3}i))(z-(2-\sqrt{3}i))=0.$$ Hence the solution set is $\{-1,2+\sqrt{3}i,2-\sqrt{3}i\}$ and the sketch is:

[image: Sketch of the solution set]

Is it okay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, your work is correct.

You have factored the polynomial correctly. You have found the roots and plotted the roots on  the complex plane.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is fine. Here is an alternative way to do it. 
$$z^3-3z^2+3z+7=0$$
$$\Longrightarrow (z-1)^3=(-2)^3$$
$$\Longrightarrow z=1-2, 1-2\omega, 1-2\omega^2$$
where $\omega$ is a cube root of unity.

Also, now it becomes much easier to plot the roots on argand plane, just plot the cube roots of unity and apply transformation.